# Why are there only two charges - positive and negative? Why not more or less?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, charge

What happens if theoretically there were more or less charges?

Comment: I'm not for esoteric thoughts, but a long time ago the Chinese found that all or mostly all phenomena have two sides, called Ying and Yang. Beside the two charges the electric and the magnetic field seems to be two undependent field, which do not influence each other. But charged particles have both a magnetic dipole moment and an electric field and only by this we could produce electricity. And sometimes both Ying and Yang are connected to one unit. So the atom is the connection of the charged particles electron and proton *and* neutrons as their "sum".

Comment: Until disapproval quarks (or discovery of smaller units) are a phenomenon with more than 2 constituents.